# Is it possible to add an anchor/param to links with Kaminari?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

I'm using pagination with Kaminari. It's working awesome.

One thing that I want for now is, adding `#comment_section` behind the url that Kaminari generates.

For example, my views is just like this. I'd like it to goes to the top of this section when page is loaded by clicking the link that Kaminari generated.

Is it possible?

```
<a name="comment_section">
<span id="comment">
 <%= render 'users/comment' %>
</span>
<%= paginate @comments, :window => 4 %>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807653/is-it-possible-to-add-anchor-tags-to-kaminari-urls

Comment: Thanks but it seems there's no answer:(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Kaminari documentation](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#helpers):

```
<%= paginate @users, params: { controller: 'foo', action: 'bar'} %>
```

So I guess you can modify it to have an anchor param, in your case:

```
<%= paginate @users, params: { anchor: 'comment_section' } %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped! But one mistake. I didn't need # . so please update your answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: @MrYoshiji I've tried this, but it doesn't working. Should I change kaminari views for new param?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember right but it should work.

in view

```
<%= paginate @posts, :remote => true, :param_name => "post_page" %>
<%= paginate @comments, :remote => true, :param_name => "comment_page" %>
```

in controller

```
@posts = Post.search(query).page(params[:user_page])
@comments = Post.search(query).page(params[:post_page])
```